# How to increase the width of Xcode Autocomplete Suggestion Window

Tags: ios, xcode, autocomplete, editing

Is there any way to increase Autocomplete window width, so that it would be possible to actually use it?

Currently, there is no way to distinguish between the long method names in `UIKit`, such as this one:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

[image: Xcode Autocomplete Window is tailored to Macbook 12]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now drag with the cursor to resize its width (first noticed in Xcode 11.3, not sure about earlier versions).

Answer (score 4):

**NO WAY SO FAR.**

There is no way to customize the width of auto completion suggestion window.

Comment: Are there any hacks in UserDefaults? e.g. `defaults write com.apple.finder appleshowallfiles yes` ?

Comment: So far my knowledge with Mac OS X & Xcode, since 7 years, I never seen such. When we face it, we simply hit ENTER, & See, or type more specific, if we remember name completely.

Comment: Ok, so it seems the best way to handle it is to ditch the Xcode completely.